# web api add route based on httprequest

Tags: dynamic, odata, asp.net-web-api2, wcf-data-services

For routing in the web api, routes are added in the `Application_Start` event in `global.asax`.

Example:
http://localhost/Products

Only after the request is received, "Products" is parsed from URL and corresponding properties needs to be generated.

How and where should I add a new route based on each incoming HTTP request? (besides Application_Start) Existence of "products" is not known until runtime.

For this scenario, must I use a wcf data service with an untyped custom data service provider? Or can I use web api 2.2 instead?

Answer (score -1):

WebApi OData does support creating Edm Model per request. For more information, please reference the [Dynamic EDM Model Creation sample](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation/) on codeplex.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Due to the nature of the web, they might disappear. Please include a brief summary or code sample for posterity.